# Creating buttons from a list with TKinter - using the list items as labels

Tags: python, list, tkinter, button

I'm currently trying to (re-)create a card game with Python 3.10 and Tkinter. I now want to code a hand of cards which is drawn dynamically each round. The number of cards drawn may vary (value is stored in `drawHandCalc()`). My problem is this: I want every card (a button on screen) to be named the correct item from the list of cards (the deck), this is what I got so far:

```
drawing_deck = starting_deck
random.shuffle(drawing_deck)
i = 0
while i < drawHandCalc():
    drawnCard = tk.StringVar()
    drawnCard.set(drawing_deck[i])
    print(drawing_deck[i])
    handcardVar = Button(root, text=str(drawnCard), padx=30, pady=80)
    handcardVar.grid(row=3, column=3+i)
    i += 1
```

I want to access item [i] in the list `drawing_deck` and use it as the label for the button. The print in console works fine, but on the UI, the buttons are labeled `PY_VAR1 , PY_VAR2, PY_VAR3` and so on. Why does this happen and how can I get Tkinter to use the string item from the list `drawing_deck`?

**Solved!**
As jasonharper pointed out, I used the name of the StringVar, not the contents. The code below works as intended!

```
while i < drawHandCalc():
    drawnCard = tk.StringVar()
    drawnCard.set(drawing_deck[i])
    print(drawing_deck[i])
    handcardVar = Button(root, text=drawnCard.get(), padx=30, pady=80)
    handcardVar.grid(row=3, column=3+i)
    i += 1
```

Comment: `str(drawnCard)` isn't the *contents* of the StringVar (that would be written `drawnCard.get()`), it's the *name* of the StringVar (an internal detail that you will seldom care about).

Comment: Yup! That worked perfectly, thank you! I was wondering where the text "PY_VAR" was even coming from, but your explanation makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using a `StringVar` and then throwing away the reference? Why not just use `text=drawing_deck[i]`?

Comment: I tried doing that at first, but it turned out that Tkinter needs the `StringVar` , so that the labels would update correctly. With `text=drawing_deck[i]` all labels would have the first item ( `drawing_deck[0]` ) as text labels.

EDIT: I just tried `text = drawing_deck[i]` again, this time it worked... oops. so, thanks!

Comment: @globuscodingworld: tkinter never requires the use of a `StringVar`. Though, you can use a `StringVar` to have two widgets display the same data, or have a label update automatically when the `StringVar` changes. For that updating to work you need to use the `textvariable` option, not the `text` option. You also need to keep a reference to the `StringVar` so that you can change its value.